# Doing complex queries with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I query with jQuery for any `DIV` element that is `visible`, has `z-index > 0` and `id != ""`.

I currently do a raw linear search using `document.getElementsByTagName` but I have been told that it's excessively performance-impacting. On a page with 400+ divs it takes quite a lot of time to perform.

Somebody told me that with jQuery you can perform more complex queries. Is that possible?

Please bear in mind that I have absolutely no control over IDs of these popup DIVs so I can't work on "well-known" IDs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery features a [very rich set of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (nearly all of CSS3 and few extras). Combined with the handy [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function, you can do very useful things:

```
var divsWithZIndexAndID = $('div:visible[id!=""]').filter(function() {
    return parseInt(this.style.zIndex, 10) > 0;
});
```

That looks specifically at the `z-index` on the element's inline style. If you need computed style, use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
var divsWithZIndexAndID = $('div:visible[id!=""]').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10) > 0;
});
```

(Both `style.zIndex` and `css` return strings, hence the `parseInt`. JavaScript would automatically make a number out of it anyway, but using `parseInt` lets me be clear about the radix that should be applied.)

Comment: `z-index` is a CSS property, not an HTML attribute. I don't think your selector would work.

Comment: @TJ: `div:visible[z-index][id!=""]`

Comment: @Tomalak: Gah! Thank you, fixed. @Tomalak & @Frédéric: Thanks for pointing those out, I'm off this morning...

Answer (score 4):

Separate your query into parts that can be handles by jQuery selectors (such as searching for visible elements those that have non-empty `id` attribute) and those that can not (e.g. the `z-index` inequality filtering). You can then code the first class of filters as normal selectors and the second using `filter` function and arbitrary predicate.

Example:

```
$("div:visible[id!='']").filter(function()
    { return parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) > 0; }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var $objs = $('div:visible[id!=""]').filter(function() {
   return this.style.zIndex > 0;
});
```

You should add handling for when `this.style.zIndex` is equal to `auto`.